# How do I clear the default email client?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, defaults

I do not want ANY email client as a default. Whenever I accidentally click on a link, Outlook comes up. I do not want ANYTHING to pop up.

Uninstalling is not an option. I want Outlook on the computer; I just do not want a default or anything to open if I accidentally click on a mail-link.

How can I clear the default?

I'm on OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score -1):

The location you set your default email reader is in Mail.app:

Mail > Preferences > General

That will let you pick a different program than Outlook, but doesn't have a none option.

There is a third party system preference that I have, but I can't tell if it is discontinued or the developer's site is just down. It lets you set a default application for all sorts of "various URL schemes, file extensions, file types, Uniform Type Identifiers (UTIs), and MIME types."
[RCDefaultApp](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14618/rcdefaultapp)

One of the options under email is `<disabled>` which should be what you want.